# Is there a hidden inner product in these amplitudes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, polarization, yang-mills

In chapter 16.3 of Peskin & Schroeder we make use of the optical theorem to show that the Ward identity is indeed preserved if we take into account ghosts in a non-Abelian gauge theory. Then in equation 16.37 we want to calculate the quantity
$$
\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\rho}g_{\nu\sigma}\mathcal{M}'^{\rho\sigma}
$$
where $\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}$ is the amplitude for fermion-anti-fermion annihillation and $\mathcal{M}'^{\rho\sigma}$ is the amplitude for a pair of gauge bosons to convert to fermion-anti-fermion. To compute this we make use of the completeness relation
$$
g_{\mu\nu}=\epsilon_\mu^-\epsilon_\nu^{+*}+\epsilon_\mu^+\epsilon_\nu^{-*}-\sum_i\epsilon_{i\mu}^T\epsilon_{i\nu}^T
$$
and hence we have
$$
\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}\left(\epsilon^-_\mu\epsilon^{+*}_\rho + \epsilon^+_\mu\epsilon_\rho^{-*}-\sum_i\epsilon_{i\mu}^T\epsilon_{i\rho}^T\right)\left(\epsilon^-_\nu\epsilon^{+*}_\sigma + \epsilon^+_\nu\epsilon_\sigma^{-*}-\sum_i\epsilon_{i\nu}^T\epsilon_{i\sigma}^T\right)\mathcal{M}'^{\rho\sigma}
$$
then we make an assumption I'm not sure I understand. We assumed that terms of the form
$$
\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^-_\mu\epsilon^-_\nu\epsilon^{+*}_\rho\epsilon^{+*}_\sigma \mathcal{M}'^{\rho\sigma}=0
$$
Why should that be true? I know and understand why $(\epsilon^{\pm})^2=0$ but here we are not taking the innder product of these polarisation states.

Note: The polarisation states $\epsilon^T$ are the transverse ones, which we don't really consider here because they do vanish in the Ward identity. Then the polarisation states $\epsilon^{\pm}$ are the forward/backward lightlike polarization states. As shown in page 511.